# Discord.js - Cannot read property 'voice' of undefined

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm using slash commands

```
client.ws.on('INTERACTION_CREATE', async (interaction) => {}
...
const memberVoice = interaction.member.voice.channel;
```

Error:
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'voice' of undefined`

I don't understand because it says in the docs that `interaction` has property `member` and `member` has `voice` so it doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

In the Discord API docs it says, that the member has a property called `voice_states` which in return has the property `channel_id`.

I think this is what you are looking for:

```js
const memberVoice = interaction.member.voice_states.channel_id;
```